# Break out of the 'nested loop' when condition is met, and then continue the loop of the parent loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, break

I have a nested loop, but I only need the first condition of the child loop. So I need the child loop to stop when it meets the condition, and restart the loop for the index of the parent loop. The example should clarify. I have first few rows of the dataframe:

```
    M#  Date    Time    Day Team    Team2   Venue   Team3   days_between1   next_game1
26  27  2021-05-01  7.30 pm Sat MI  CSK Delhi   MI CSK  0   0
27  28  2021-05-02  3.30 pm Sun RR  SRH Delhi   RR SRH  0   0
28  29  2021-05-02  7.30 pm Sun PK  DC  Ahmedabad   PK DC   0   0
29  30  2021-05-03  7.30 pm Mon KKR RCB Ahmedabad   KKR RCB 0   0
30  31  2021-05-04  7.30 pm Tue SRH MI  Delhi   SRH MI  0   0
31  32  2021-05-05  7.30 pm Wed RR  CSK Delhi   RR CSK  0   0
32  33  2021-05-06  7.30 pm Thur    RCB PK  Ahmedabad   RCB PK  0   0
33  34  2021-05-07  7.30 pm Fri SRH CSK Delhi   SRH CSK 0   0
34  35  2021-05-08  3.30 pm Sat KKR DC  Ahmedabad   KKR DC  0   0
```

I am trying to calculate the number of days between the games a particular team plays. For example, MI plays on the first and the fourth. I have created a column 'Team3' that contains the names of both teams playing to make setting the condition easier. This is my attempt:

```
for i in range(26, df.last_valid_index()):
  a = df['Team'][i]
  for j in range(i,df.last_valid_index()):
    t = df['Team3'][j]
    if t.find(a) != -1:
      df['days_between1'][i] = df['Date'][j] - df['Date'][i]
```

The result should look something like this:

```
    M#  Date    Time    Day Team    Team2   Venue   Team3   days_between1   next_game1
26  27  2021-05-01  7.30 pm Sat MI  CSK Delhi   MI CSK  3   0
27  28  2021-05-02  3.30 pm Sun RR  SRH Delhi   RR SRH  3   0
28  29  2021-05-02  7.30 pm Sun PK  DC  Ahmedabad   PK DC   3   0
29  30  2021-05-03  7.30 pm Mon KKR RCB Ahmedabad   KKR RCB 3   0
30  31  2021-05-04  7.30 pm Tue SRH MI  Delhi   SRH MI  1   0
31  32  2021-05-05  7.30 pm Wed RR  CSK Delhi   RR CSK  NA  0
32  33  2021-05-06  7.30 pm Thur    RCB PK  Ahmedabad   RCB PK  NA  0
33  34  2021-05-07  7.30 pm Fri SRH CSK Delhi   SRH CSK NA  0
34  35  2021-05-08  3.30 pm Sat KKR DC  Ahmedabad   KKR DC  NA  0
```

Comment: Are you looking for something more complicated than `break`?

Comment: @TimRoberts I wasn't able to use break in a way to create the desired output.

Comment: You just need a combination of `break` and a variable set to `True` that breaks the outer loop. That said, you shouldn't really be using [loops with data frames](https://towardsdatascience.com/you-dont-always-have-to-loop-through-rows-in-pandas-22a970b347ac)

Comment: Can you provide a sample output with the necessary columns in use. Most probably this can be done without looping in pandas.

Comment: @Utsav the last table is what I think it should look like (hand calculated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the loop into a [**`DataFrame.apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Find the [**`first_valid_index()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html) that matches a given `team` and subtract the matched date from the `team`'s date:

```py
def between(row):
    index, team = row.name, row.Team
    mask = df[['Team', 'Team2']].loc[index+1:] == team
    match = mask.replace(False, np.nan).first_valid_index()
    return df.loc[match, 'Date'] - df.loc[index, 'Date'] if match else np.nan

df.days_between1 = df.apply(between, axis=1)

#     M#  Date        Time     Day   Team  Team2  Venue      Team3    days_between1  next_game1
# 26  27  2021-05-01  7.30 pm  Sat   MI    CSK    Delhi      MI CSK   3 days         0
# 27  28  2021-05-02  3.30 pm  Sun   RR    SRH    Delhi      RR SRH   3 days         0
# 28  29  2021-05-02  7.30 pm  Sun   PK    DC     Ahmedabad  PK DC    4 days         0
# 29  30  2021-05-03  7.30 pm  Mon   KKR   RCB    Ahmedabad  KKR RCB  5 days         0
# 30  31  2021-05-04  7.30 pm  Tue   SRH   MI     Delhi      SRH MI   3 days         0
# 31  32  2021-05-05  7.30 pm  Wed   RR    CSK    Delhi      RR CSK   NaT            0
# 32  33  2021-05-06  7.30 pm  Thur  RCB   PK     Ahmedabad  RCB PK   NaT            0
# 33  34  2021-05-07  7.30 pm  Fri   SRH   CSK    Delhi      SRH CSK  NaT            0
# 34  35  2021-05-08  3.30 pm  Sat   KKR   DC     Ahmedabad  KKR DC   NaT            0
```

Comment: I am still trying to understand this but I am very unfamiliar with this type of coding. Could you tell me what I would have to change to find a 'days_between2' column that does the same thing but instead looks at the number of days between games in the 'Team2' column?

Comment: @KushalMohnot the most straightforward way would be to change `row.Team` to `row.Team2` in the function's first line: `index, team = row.name, row.Team2`

Comment: that was my guess too, but for some reason df.days_between2 = df.apply(between, axis=1) was not working after I initialized a df['days_between2'] = 0. I used this: df['days_between2'] = df.apply(between, axis=1) and it worked. Thank you once again, you have been awesome!

Comment: @KushalMohnot yes good point, you can only assign into dot notation `df.days_between2` if the column already exists. you can assign into bracket notation `df['days_between2']` even if it doesn't exist yet